# Form won't post on localhost

Tags: php, html, forms

I have no idea what is going on here, but my form won't post. I've stripped it back to absolute basics, but still no joy. Get works fine and I'm working on MAMP on localhost.

Here it is: simplest form in the world that won't work.

```
<?php  
  print_r($_POST);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="">
<head>
<title>Site Title</title>
</head>
  <body class="wrapper">
<p>This is the form</p>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" />
      <input type="submit" name="fSubmit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've probably missed something so stupid, hence getting some more eyes on it!

Cheers

Comment: are you sure `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is returning what you think it is? Also, don't you need a semicolon after that echo?

Comment: rather than posting the html with mixed php, look at the raw html in the developer console (f12 in chrome) and post that, if that doesn't show the error

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem, I just yanked your code and pasted it. It works fine with WAMP Server. May be there is a problem with your webserver and php settings (Just a hunch).

Answer (score 1):

Alright folks. Thanks for all your ideas - I had already tried EVERY POSSIBLE combination of actions, names, etc... I had the corret hml headers posted to the page. I just restarted my mac and re-ran the servers and everything seems to be ok. I have no idea what went wrong, but it seems to be fixed now.

Apologies for the fairly useless question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
<?php  
  print_r($_POST);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="">
<head>
<title>Site Title</title>
</head>
  <body class="wrapper">
<p>This is the form</p>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" />
      <input type="submit" name="fSubmit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

or even just make sure php is installed/enabled

Comment: oh and maybe use firebug or something to check what headers are being sent and such, might give you an idea if its actually submitting it or not!